# Vagrant - Failed to mount folders in Linux Guest using Puphpet and SMB mounting

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows, puphpet

I'm trying to set up Vagrant on Windows 10.

I have Vagrant 2.0.1, Virtual Box 5.2.4 and Guest Additions 5.2.4.

I had issues whilst Virtual Box and Guest Additions were not the same versions, but now I've bought them inline with each other I still get an error.

I am running Git Bash as Administrator too. Here is the output from git bash.

The vagrantfile is generated through Puphpet and I didn't really change much within puphpet setup. I added SMB for the shared folders as it recommended this. I did not supply a username or password, and when prompted for both during `vagrant up` I just leave them both blank.

I've seen and read the other articles on SO and not had any luck with them.

```
$ vagrant up Bringing machine 'machine1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> machine1: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'...
==> machine1: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> machine1: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' is up to date...
==> machine1: Setting the name of the VM: Ubuntu_machine1_1517300867334_22288
==> machine1: Preparing SMB shared folders...
    machine1: You will be asked for the username and password to use for the SMB
    machine1: folders shortly. Please use the proper username/password of your
    machine1: Windows account.
    machine1:
    machine1: Username:
    machine1: Password (will be hidden): Error! Your console doesn't support hiding input. We'll ask for input again below, but we WILL NOT be able to hide input. If this is a problem for you, ctrl-C to exit and fix your stdin.
     machine1: Password (will be hidden):
==> machine1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> machine1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    machine1: Adapter 1: nat
    machine1: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> machine1: Forwarding ports...
    machine1: 22 (guest) => 5741 (host) (adapter 1)
    machine1: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> machine1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> machine1: Booting VM...
==> machine1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    machine1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    machine1: SSH username: vagrant
    machine1: SSH auth method: private key
==> machine1: Machine booted and ready! [machine1] GuestAdditions 5.2.4 running --- OK.
==> machine1: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> machine1: Setting hostname...
==> machine1: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> machine1: Mounting SMB shared folders...
    machine1: E:/Simon/Sites => /var/www Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and can work properly. The command attempted was:

PASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDENoPASSWORDHIDDENuPASSWORDHIDDENnPASSWORDHIDDENtPASSWORDHIDDEN PASSWORDHIDDEN-PASSWORDHIDDENtPASSWORDHIDDEN PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDEN PASSWORDHIDDEN-PASSWORDHIDDENoPASSWORDHIDDEN PASSWORDHIDDENuPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENgPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDENyPASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDENlPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENnPASSWORDHIDDENkPASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENrPASSWORDHIDDEN_PASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDENoPASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN7PASSWORDHIDDEN7PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENlPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDEN_PASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDENoPASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENvPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDENrPASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN.PASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDENnPASSWORDHIDDENtPASSWORDHIDDENlPASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDEN,PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDENrPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDENnPASSWORDHIDDENtPASSWORDHIDDENiPASSWORDHIDDENaPASSWORDHIDDENlPASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDEN=PASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDENtPASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDENmPASSWORDHIDDENbPASSWORDHIDDEN_PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDENrPASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDENdPASSWORDHIDDENsPASSWORDHIDDEN_PASSWORDHIDDENbPASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDENbPASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDENaPASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN8PASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDEN7PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN PASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN9PASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDEN.PASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDEN8PASSWORDHIDDEN.PASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN.PASSWORDHIDDEN7PASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDENbPASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDENePASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDENbPASSWORDHIDDEN2PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDENaPASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN5PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN1PASSWORDHIDDEN8PASSWORDHIDDEN6PASSWORDHIDDENfPASSWORDHIDDEN0PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDEN4PASSWORDHIDDEN7PASSWORDHIDDEN3PASSWORDHIDDENcPASSWORDHIDDEN PASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDENvPASSWORDHIDDENaPASSWORDHIDDENrPASSWORDHIDDEN/PASSWORDHIDDENwPASSWORDHIDDENwPASSWORDHIDDENwPASSWORDHIDDEN

The error output from the last command was:

mount error(13): Permission denied Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I also have a plugin installed. As suggested by other SO answers. Still no luck: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

Answer (score 2):

So after reading closer, the username/password it asks for is your windows username and password. Now, that doesn't help in windows 10 if you have run through the setup process and created a Windows account online. If you have the same problems as me, make sure to check your account settings under account management, and "switch to local account" to create a local account for yourself. You'll be prompted to supply a password (needed, as PIN didn't work either). Log in to this user, and try again supplying your new credentials.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: goddamn it. thanks. do you know how to use make smb work with the microsoft account instead of local?

Comment: You do not need to create a local account, You can use your "User" folder name (inside "C:\Users") as username and also use your windows online account! I worked for me!